# Batch scheduler time , status and account

Tags: scheduled-apex

I'm stuck for one of the requirements .

Have to check the Status , Time and Name/created by of the Batch Schedular .Have a query working for CronTrigger for this but how do i implement it through Visualforce page ?

An example will help me to reach my destination.

Answer (score 1):

Sharing some code I happen to have closely available, although not exactly what you're asking for, pretty close.

```
public class CronJob {
    public Id jobId { get; private set; }
    public String jobName { get; private set; } 
    public CronTrigger obj { get; private set; }

    public CronJob(CronTrigger ct) {
        jobId = ct.Id;
        jobName = ct.CronJobDetail.Name;
        obj = ct;
    }

    public pageReference unschedule() {
        System.abortJob( jobId );
        return null;
    }
}

public list<CronJob> getScheduledJobs() {
    list<CronJob> cj = new list<CronJob>();
    for (CronTrigger ct : [SELECT Id, CronJobDetailId, CronJobDetail.Name, 
            NextFireTime, PreviousFireTime, State, StartTime, EndTime, CronExpression, 
            CreatedBy.Name, CreatedDate, TimesTriggered from CronTrigger
            WHERE CronJobDetail.JobType = '7'
            ORDER BY CronJobDetail.Name]) {

        cj.add( new CronJob( ct ) );
    }
    return cj;
}
```

Comment: And how do i add this in Page block table ? Want to display column wise in a table..

Comment: I'm not going to write all of your code for you. The Visualforce docs outline how to repeat over a list pretty well: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_pageBlockTable.htm